# How to Change Position of an Item that Appears in Thunar Context Menu

Tags: linux, xfce, thunar

**Thunar** **1.6.11** (Debian Stretch)

**Thunar** is loaded on two different machines. When I right click on a `.zip` file, the context menu on one machine displays the **Extract Here** option fairly high up on the menu. On the other machine, said option is listed near the bottom of the context menu.

This option is *not* a user-added Custom Action.

How can I get the **Extract Here** option to be listed higher up on the context menu?

Answer (score 1):

I went through all my Thunar Options.

There is no option for change contexts or context position.

Here are the main options:

[image: Thunar Options]

Here are the advanced Config Settings using its file. None of the settings I can see would affect contexts or context position.

[Thunar settings](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/hidden-settings)

Comment: I'm suspecting that this problem may require getting into one or more configuration files, at the least...

Comment: I added a link to the Thunar settings. There are a number of hidden settings but none (that I can see) affecting context.